# PHP MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 encryption in C#

Tags: php, c#-4.0, encryption

I'm trying to rewrite this function in C#. but the C# output mismatches the php

PHP version

```
// Encrypt data using AES128-cbc
function encrypt($data, $key, $iv) {
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
    $multipass = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    return $multipass;
}
```

C# Version

```
public static string encrypt(string encryptionString, string iv, string key)
{
    byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionString);
    var rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
    rijn.KeySize = 128;
    rijn.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv)), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);
    cs.Close();
    var tmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you jump through those `CryptoStream` + `MemoryStream` hoops when you could simply call `rijn.TransformFinalBlock`?

Comment: To others trying to get this to work, PaddingMode.Zeros (Syon's answer below) was the solution for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encrypt/Decrypt using PHP:

```
class Cipher {
    private $key, $iv;
    function __construct() {
        $this->key = "edrtjfjfjlldldld";
        $this->iv = "56666852251557009888889955123458";
    }
    function encrypt($text) {

        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $padding = $block - (strlen($text) % $block);
        $text .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);

        return base64_encode($crypttext);
    }

    function decrypt($input) {
        $dectext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->key, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);
        return $dectext;
    }
}
```

Encrypt/Decrypt using C#:

```
public class RijndaelSimple
    {
        const string iv = "56666852251557009888889955123458";
        const string key = "edrtjfjfjlldldld";

        static public String EncryptRJ256(string plainText)
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var Key = encoding.GetBytes(key);
            var IV = encoding.GetBytes(iv);
            byte[] encrypted;

            using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                try
                {
                    rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    rj.KeySize = 256;
                    rj.BlockSize = 256;
                    rj.Key = Key;
                    rj.IV = IV;

                    var ms = new MemoryStream();

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        {
                            sr.Write(plainText);
                            sr.Flush();
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }
                        encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    rj.Clear();
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

        static public String DecryptRJ256(string input)
        {
            byte[] cypher = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

            var sRet = "";

            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var Key = encoding.GetBytes(key);
            var IV = encoding.GetBytes(iv);

            using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                try
                {
                    rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    rj.KeySize = 256;
                    rj.BlockSize = 256;
                    rj.Key = Key;
                    rj.IV = IV;
                    var ms = new MemoryStream(cypher);

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                        {
                            sRet = sr.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    rj.Clear();
                }
            }

            return sRet;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Two issues with your C# code.

1. You should not be encoding the contents of your `MemoryStream` to UTF8. The output of the `CryptoStream` is binary and will not convert properly. Either return a `byte[]`, or if you really want a string, encode the output to Hex or Base64.
2. You need to set the padding mode via `rijn.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;`. Although it's not clearly stated, PHP pads data up to the block size using 0's. The default for padding for `SymmetricAlgorithm` is PKCS7.

Also note that the signatures of your PHP and C# methods are different. The parameter order for your PHP function is `data, key, iv` while the C# method is `data, iv, key`. If you're still having an issue after the changes I've listed above, it may be that your IV and key are reversed when calling your C# encrypt method.

Comment: @nullException: Does this not solve your issue? Testing these changes with your code fixes it for me.

Comment: +1 your Item 2 is a good point, however Melad's solution is adding PKCS7 padding to text too (and should be removed later), so results should be same in both C# and PHP (I get same result in both)

Comment: @Syon +1 ... PaddingMode.Zeros was the problem for me, though I found the tip somewhere else. Your answer needs more upvotes!